# Algorithm to find first sequence of integers that sum to certain value

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pseudocode, memoization

I have a list of numbers and I have a sum value. For instance,

`list = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 10, 23, 24, 54, 79 ]`

`sum = 20`

I would like to generate a sequence  of numbers taken from that list, such that the sequence sums up to that target. In order to help achieve this, the sequence can be of any length and repetition is allowed.

`result = [2, 3, 5, 10]` ,or `result = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5]` ,or `result = [10, 10]`

I've been doing a lot of research into this problem and have found the **[subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)** problem to be of interest. My problem is, in a few ways, similar to the subset sum problem in that I would like to find a subset of numbers that produces the targeted sum.

However, unlike the subset sum problem which finds *all* sets of numbers that sum up to the target (and so runs in exponential time if brute forcing), I only want to find *one* set of numbers. I want to find the first set that gives me the sum. So, in a certain sense, speed is a factor.

Additionally, I would like there to be some degree of *randomness* (or pseudo-randomness) to the algorithm. That is, should I run the algorithm using the same list and sum multiple times, I should get a different set of numbers each time.

What would be the best algorithm to achieve this?

**Additional Notes:** 
What I've achieved so far is using a naive method where I cycle through the list adding it to every combination of values. This obviously takes a long time and I'm currently not feeling too happy about it. I'm hoping there is a better way to do this!

If there is no sequence that gives me the exact sum, I'm satisfied with a sequence that gives me a sum that is *as close as* possible to the targeted sum.

Comment: Couldn't you just take the an algorithm for the subset sum problem, and exit the algorithm once it finds the first solution? There has to be some place in the algorithm where a solution is found and added to the list of solutions. If that happens, exit out.

Comment: a) `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5]` is not a subset. b) define "first" in that context

Comment: I think that this is the rucksack problem. It is NP-complete, that is, no algorithm beyond brute force search can exist.

Comment: what do you mean by "first"? for example what would be first using the data from your question, `[2,3,5,10]` or `[10,10]`. And are all integers positive? this is of importance aswell.

Comment: Nitpicking: Yes, there are algorithms other than brute force for NP problems. Just not "fast" algorithms.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear... what I mean by "first" is whichever sequence is "found first". That is, if the algorithm "finds" sequence [2, 3, 5, 10] before [10, 10] to match the targeted sum then [2,3 ,5, 10] is "first"

Answer (score 1):

As others said, this is a NP-problem.
However, this doesn't mean small improvements aren't possible:

Is 1 in the list? `[1,1,1,1...]` is the solution. O(1) in a sorted list

Remove list element bigger than the target sum. O(n)

Is there any list element x with `(x%sum)==0` ? Again, easy solution. O(n)

Are there any list elements x,y with `(x%y)==0` ? Remove x. O(n^2)
(maybe even: Are there any list elements x,y,z with `(x%y)==z` or `(x+y)==z` ? Remove x. O(n^3))

Before using the full recursion, try if you can get the sum
just with the smallest even and smallest odd number.

...

Comment: In case `(x+y)==z` you should remove `z`

Answer (score 0):

Subset Sum problem isn't about finding all subsets, but rather about determining if there is some subset. It is a [decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem). All problems in [NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)) are like this. And even this simpler problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

This means that if you want an exact answer (the subset must sum exactly some value) you won't be able to do much better than the any subset sum algorithm (it is exponential unless [P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%3D_NP_problem)).

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to reduce the problem to a brute-force search of a smaller set.

- Sort the `list` smallest to largest.
- Keep a `sum` and `result` list.

Repeat {

- Draw randomly from the subset of `list` less than `target - sum`.
- Increment `sum` by drawn value, add drawn value to `result` list.

} until `list[0] > sum` or `sum == 0`

- If `sum != 0`, brute force search for small combinations from `list` that match the difference between `sum` and small combinations of `result`.

This approach may fail to find valid solutions, even if they exist.  It can, however, quickly find a solution or quickly fail before having to resort to a slower brute force approach using the entire set at a greater depth.

Answer (score 0):

This is a greedy approach to the problem:

Without 'randomness':

Obtain the single largest number in the set that is smaller than your desired sum- we'll name it *X*. Given it's ordered, at best it's *O(1)*, and *O(N)* at worst if the sum is 2.

As you can repeat the value- say *c* times, do so as many times until you get closest to the sum, but be careful! Create a range of values- essentially now you'll be finding another sum! You'll now be find numbers that add up to *R* = (sum - *X* * *c*). So find the largest number smaller than *R*. Check if *R* - (number you just found) = 0 or if any [*R* - (number you just found)] % (smaller #s) == 0.

If it becomes *R* > 0, make partial sums of the smaller numbers less than *R* (this will not be more than 5 ~ 10 computations because of the nature of this algorithm). See if these would then satisfy it.

If that step makes *R* < 0, remove one *X* and start the process again.

With 'randomness':

Just get *X* randomly! :-)

Note: This would work best if you have a few single digit numbers.